# Why is hydrogen bonding stronger than dipole-dipole interaction of carbonyls?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

My understanding was that hydrogen bonding is much stronger than other dipole-dipole interactions since the dipole between hydrogen and O/F/N is much greater than other dipoles. However, the dipole between C and O in carbonyl is apparently greater than that of a hydroxy group in, say, an alcohol. Hydrogen bonding is still said to be stronger. Why is that?

Comment: If it was just a  dipole-dipole interaction there would be no reason to set it apart.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/143419/why-hydrogen-bonds-are-stronger-than-van-der-waals-forces

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/what-exactly-is-hydrogen-bonding-and-does-it-really-need-fluorine-oxygen-or-n